# Not receiving Email from Azure AD login using Owin OpenIdConnect

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, owin

I have a MVC web application that uses Owin's OpenIdConnector OAuth provider to authenticate against a multi-tenant Azure AD directory.

I can redirect to the Microsoft login page and return to my app, but when I call the `GetExternalLoginInfo` method the Email property is always null.

I suspect this is because of the permissions I am setting on the application, but I can't find what permissions I should be requesting for email to come across properly.

The permissions I'm requesting:
[image: permissions requested]

My OpenIDConnect configuration in `Startup.Auth.cs`

```
string clientId = "ClientId";
string appKey = "Client Secret";
string graphResourceID = "https://graph.windows.net";
string Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = Authority,
        TokenValidationParameters = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = false,
        },
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
            {
                var code = context.Code;
                ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
                string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}", tenantID));
                AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceID);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                {
                    string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                    context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                {
                    // retriever caller data from the incoming principal
                    string issuer = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("iss").Value;
                    string UPN = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value;
                    string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
                AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                {                            context.OwinContext.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error");
                    context.HandleResponse(); // Suppress the exception
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm having same issue. Have you found solution right after that?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the scope of the challenge when setting up the OpenIdConnectOptions. When a "challenge" is issued by your authentication scheme, the scope determines what claims to request/challenge.

```
var options = new OpenIdConnectOptions()
{
   // .... Your existing options        
};

//You'll need to check what sort of attributes you can request from azure
options.Scope.Add("profile")

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(options);
```